# Android - When click in spinner the arrow disapears

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to make a custom spinner, it's ok until we click in it and the arrow desapears like images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/component_height" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/add_spinner_account"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/component_height"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

If I use a normal spinner it works, but I need this custom spinner...
What's happend?? Anybody can help?

Comment: How do you set the arrow icon in UR custom spinner

Comment: I don't set... it's a normal code...